# C++ 2D Matrix using Vectors

Tags: c++, vector, dynamic-programming

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  int t;
  cin>>t;
  while(t--){
    int N;
    cin>>N;
    vector<vector<int>> shops(N,vector<int>(3));//What does shops(N,vector<int>(3)) mean?
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
            cin>>shops[i][j];//doubt
        }
    }
    vector<vector<int>> DP(N,vector<int>(3));
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        DP[0][i]=shops[0][i];
    }
    for(int i=1;i<N;i++){
        DP[i][0] = min(DP[i-1][1] , DP[i-1][2]) + shops[i][0]; 
        DP[i][1] = min(DP[i-1][0] , DP[i-1][2]) + shops[i][1]; 
        DP[i][2] = min(DP[i-1][0] , DP[i-1][1]) + shops[i][2];       
    }       
    int ans = min(min(DP[N-1][0], DP[N-1][1]) , DP[N-1][2]);
    cout<<ans<<"\n";
  }
}
```

The above is the implementation of this problem https://www.hackerearth.com/code-monk-dynamic-programming/algorithm/samu-and-shopping/
In this,we declared a 2D matrix using vectors but during the input we pass a singular data Ex: 1 50 50 
I am confused as there should be 2 items/data as it is a 2D matrix

Comment: The line with the comment create a vector `shops` of N elements. It so turns out, that the every element of the vector `shops` is a vector of integers. An example value of a vector of ints could be: vector<int>(3), an initialized 3-element vector. Putting it all together: the line creates a vector `shops` with 3 elements, each being a vector of 3 integers.

Comment: The doubtful line is a "read from standard input" call, for inputting value into `shops[i][j]`. I'd strongly recommend a C++ tutorial. Also - the code is far from good (but I suppose this is a contest-style, fast written, unfortunate piece of code).

Answer (score 0):

Your example:

```
-1 50 50
```

means: put value: -1 into cell at 50,50 of the matrix?

Note: This is a 2D matrix of *integers*. If you want "2 items/data" you may need a 2D matrix of *integer pairs*, e.g.:

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>>
```

Comment: I am sorry its 1 50 50

Comment: Ok I get it now that we are creating a 3-element vector but the only confusion for me is this topcoder tutorial which says:  " int N, N; 
 // ... 
 vector< vector<int> > Matrix(N, vector<int>(M, -1)); Here we create a matrix of size N*M and fill it with -1. "  So are we creating a matrix [m]x[n]?

Comment: A matrix NxM. The first dimension of `shops` goes up to N, with every element being the vector<int>(M, -1), hence the second dimension goes up to M. Consider an example: `std::vector<int> simpleVectorOfInts(10, -1)`. It's very similiar to an array `int array[10]`. Now replace `int` with `std::vector<int>` and you get the vector of vectors.